# Runtime error 424: object required with FileDialog.SourceDataFile & fdgOpen.SelectedItems(1)

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error, openfiledialog, filedialog

I want to prompt the user to select the raw data file, and abort if they click "Cancel" on the FileDialog box.

But i am getting the debug option and the error message "runtime error 424 object required" on the line :

FileDialog.SourceDataFile = fdgOpen.SelectedItems(1)

As i am quite new to the whole open-a-file-like-this method, any help will be appreciated!

```
    Sub Open file
    Dim fldr As FileDialog

    Dim Answer As Integer
    Dim fdgOpen As FileDialog
    sPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Skrivebord\"
    Set fdgOpen = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)


    Answer = MsgBox("Continue? ", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Update")
        If Answer = vbNo Then GoTo Nej Else
                Application.ScreenUpdating = False
                Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual


                fdgOpen.Title = "FileDialogTitle"
                fdgOpen.InitialFileName = "Select raw data"
                fdgOpen.Show

                    If fdgOpen.SelectedItems.Count <= 0 Then GoTo Nej Else
                    FileDialog.SourceDataFile = fdgOpen.SelectedItems(1)

    Nej: MsgBox ("You cancelled")

End sub
```

Comment: I can check this but why are you not using Excel's inbuilt `Application.Getopenfilename`

Comment: BTW what is `FileDialog` in `FileDialog.SourceDataFile`

Comment: I found this code, so that could explain why lol. It worked yesterday for whatever reason, i just can't get my head around this part. 
If you got a better way to do it, please enlighten me!! It'd be most helpful

Comment: Sure but please explain what do you want to do with the selected file?

Comment: Thank you! I "just" want the user to navigate to raw data file, then open it as the raw data can be various file-names and paths, depending on the user

Comment: IF you want excel to open it then change `FileDialog.SourceDataFile = fdgOpen.SelectedItems(1)` to `Workbooks.Open (fdgOpen.SelectedItems(1))` and add `Exit Sub` before `Nej: MsgBox ("You cancelled")` But let me post a different and a better answer

Comment: Quick question. would the user be selecting a single file or multiple files

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! Single file only! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the `Object Required` error because your code doesn't understand what `FileDialog` is in `FileDialog.SourceDataFile = fdgOpen.SelectedItems(1)`

Here is a much simpler version which uses the native Excel's `Application.GetOpenFilename`

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Openfile()
    Dim Ret, Ans

    Ans = MsgBox("Continue? ", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Update")

    If Ans = vbNo Then
        MsgBox "You cancelled"
    Else
        Ret = Application.GetOpenFilename("Raw Data Files (*.*), *.*", , "Select Raw Data")

        If Ret = False Then
            MsgBox "You cancelled"
        Else
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

            Workbooks.Open Ret

            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

This is how you will o it using the `FileDialog`

```
Sub Openfile()
    Dim dlgOpen As FileDialog
    Dim Ans
    Dim sPath As String

    Ans = MsgBox("Continue? ", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Update")

    sPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Skrivebord\"

    If Ans = vbNo Then
        MsgBox "You cancelled"
    Else
        Set dlgOpen = Application.FileDialog( _
        FileDialogType:=msoFileDialogOpen)

        With dlgOpen
            .Title = "Select Raw Data"
            '~~> Add the folder path and file name
            .InitialFileName = sPath & "Myfile.xlsx"
            .Show

            If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
                Application.ScreenUpdating = False
                Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

                Workbooks.Open .SelectedItems(1)

                Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
            Else
                MsgBox "You cancelled"
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is exactly what i needed! Thank you very much for your swift and informative help!

Comment: Any way to specify a default filename and path in this?

Comment: Nevermind, not important! It's working. Again, Thanks for your help, Siddarth

Comment: For default path, you can issue a command `CHDIR`. But if you want both then i can give an example for `FileDialog` as well

Comment: I have updated the post. Now you can take your pick ;)

Comment: Thank you, Siddharth! Great help! 
Is there a way to take into account that if it's .csv file, it should add "Local:=True" ? I have not found a solution for that so far :(

Comment: Added this instead, works for both .xls and .cvs files! \o/ 
                        Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=Ret, _
                            Origin:=xlMSDOS, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
                            ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
                            Semicolon:=True, Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
                            Other:=False, TrailingMinusNumbers:=True, _
                            Local:=True